# Custom pages with html in wordpress editor vs. writing it all directly in the php template files?

Tags: theme-development

I am building a custom theme from a previous html site I built.  Some pages I have set up using advanced custom fields so the client can change parts of those pages.  I set those up using page-{slug}.php.  I have other pages that won't change at all, also using page-{slug} for these.....is it ok to just put all the code and content in the php template?  Since if there are any changes, I will be the one handling them.

Also, this theme will never be redistributed so won't need to work on another theme.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine to do that. Wordpress doesn't care if the loop or any of the other content-related PHP in the theme file is there or runs, but you should leave `get_header()` and `get_footer()`

Comment: Yes of course get header and footer would stay. For example I would use page-about for about page. Run the loop if necessary.... and put all the content divs and html in that file. Instead of putting html into the Wordpress editor. Does this sound ok?

Comment: @user55555 yep fine! always fine to try these things also and see what happens